# Headers with Dashes in powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get rid of the header name and the dashes? For example, instead of having

```
Display Name
-------------
Test, Directory
```

It would just display the First and Last Name Test, Directory

this is what i have in my write-output:

```
write-output $DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset) | Out-null
```

I thought the `out-null` would take care of it but it didn't.

Can someone help me with that please .

Thank you.

Comment: Those are output by PowerShell's output formatter. Why do you need to get rid of them?

Comment: Or you can use `$DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset) | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders`

Comment: Well it's because i'm trying to get it to display the result underneath the F name and L Name as a value not a dataset

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell does not treat data as text; data is *objects*. Objects have properties, and when you send an object to the output pipe, the default processor will handle the conversion to text.

This conversion attempts to preserve the information about the object to the best of its ability. That means, for example, labelling the values of the properties of the object with the name of the property.

Your object, designated by `$DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset)`, has a property called `Display Name`. The default output processor `Write-Output` attempts to preserve the information by labelling the data with the property name, `Display Name`, and so you see your header.

To eliminate this, you need to output not the entire object, but the value of the specific property you are interested in:

```
Write-Output ($DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset)).'Display Name'
```

Note that - where you have control over it - having spaces as part of the property name is generally considered poor practice.

Comment: I'm trying to display the result underneath the                                   
Column1
-------
199
as a value not a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example, what you want to do is use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with the `ExpandProperty` parameter, specifying the property you want displayed.

An example of this is (without expand):

```
[1] PS G:\> Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select Name

Name         
----         
Administrator
Joe Bloggs
...
```

And with expand:

```
[2] PS G:\> Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
Administrator
Joe Bloggs
...
```

I guess the real follow up question here, though, is "why?"

By doing this you're stripping away the object based paradigm that makes PowerShell powerful. This is now just giving you an array of strings.

Comment: Without context, you can't really say that using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` is the most appropriate way. See my answer below, which also works for arrays of objects.